# How do I get the markup of an element, including itself using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I know I can wrap it's .html() in a tag, but the element itself has a dynamically set id, class, etc.  How do I get jQuery to return the element's markup including itself?

Comment: I should have stated this before, but I am working with an extreme number of items and recently found out that .append() is a processor hog. Any way to do this without .append()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no "outerHTML" support directly in jQuery, but you can write a function to emulate it (in browsers other than IE), or use [this plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml/):

```
// this will return the element and it's mark-up, of an element
// with the id myTag
var outer = $('#myTag').outerHTML();
```

Obviously Brandon's is not the only implementation.. I'm sure you could also come up with other clever implementations..

*EDIT*

If you're keen on avoiding the calls to append, maybe you could try something like this..

```
function getOuterHTML(el)
{   
    var wrapper = '';

    if(el)
    {
        var inner = el.innerHTML;
        var wrapper = '<' + el.tagName;

        for( var i = 0; i < el.attributes.length; i++ )
        {
            wrapper += ' ' + el.attributes[i].nodeName + '="';
            wrapper += el.attributes[i].nodeValue + '"';
        }
        wrapper += '>' + inner + '</' + el.tagName + '>';
    }
    return wrapper;
}


// now, to replicate the sample above
var outer = getOuterHTML($('#myTag'));
```

The only thing is, I'm not sure if all browsers support the attributes array.. but I know the mozilla-family ones do, and IE has native support for outerHTML.. give it a try (for the ones that don't support the attributes array you could use the previous method that uses appends)

Comment: I should have stated this before, but I am working with an extreme number of items and recently found out that .append() is a processor hog.  Any way to do this without .append()?

Comment: @Justin, please see the example I added to the answer. It doesn't use any appends..

Answer (score 15):

This will work well:

```
jQuery.fn.outer = function() {
    return $($('<div></div>').html(this.clone())).html();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Uhm, you don't need to use a plugin, I'm sure you can try

```
// this uses the jquery selectors, then returns the DOM element, 
// which then u can use the standard outterHTML...
$('#myelement').get(0).outerHTML;
```

Edit:  if your jquery selectors are matching more than one item, you can loop thru them, refer to the jquery docs for examples

Comment: outerHTML (it is a property, not a function btw) is not supported in Firefox (I think only IE supports it)

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-get-full-html-string-including.html) might help you.

He describes a technique that looks like this:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('#top').clone()).remove().html()
```

This clones the div of interest, appends it to a wrapper div, and then gets the html of the wrapper - which equates to the original html of the first div.

His suggestion of just surrounding it initially in a declared wrapper div seems like a better way to go though.  Then you wouldn't need to bother with all this.

Answer (score 2):

Little late to this question. If you use jQuery to find an object you can use the following code to get the outerHTML.

HTML:

```
<div class="obj">
    <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $obj = $('.obj .link');
var outerHTML = $obj[0].outerHTML;
```

That will output `<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>`. Tested on Latest Chrome, Latest Firefox and IE11. Here is a link to a codepen: http://codepen.io/aj372/pen/ZLmYbj

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, select the element, select the first inner element, get its parent (the one you want) then wrap it around the original selection from youElement.html().

Comment: That will return all children of the parent. Not just the child or children selected.